Would casting enlarge/reduce on myself to become small enough to fit through the bars of Forcecage then using druidcraft for wind let me escape?
This is somewhat of a follow-up to my last question, where I learned I can't destroy a Forcecage with brute force unless an effect actively states that I can, so now I'm trying to find out what classifies as escaping with magic.
If I'm almost small enough to fit through the bars of the cage variant of Forcecage, and I cast enlarge/reduce on myself, making me small enough to fit, and then cast druidcraft to create a gust of wind to push me through, would that count as escaping magically because the wind that pushed me through the bars was made with magic?

Also, would this allow me to be a makeshift bullet if I'm light enough?

I feel like we're starting to get to Peasant Railgun levels of rule reading here lol

@TheLittlePeace I'm 4 pounds, and 4 inches tall, so it might let me be a makeshift bullet, weighing in at .5 lbs

At that size, anybody using Forcecage on you without choosing the box option is just asking for this question to come up.

@TheLittlePeace I could also just happen to be in the radius when it's created and therefore be trapped inside, or be in my enlarged state as a path of the giant barbarian

Yes
Shrinking yourself down with reduce to fit through the bars is a magical method, so it qualifies as leaving it by magical means. For nearly any player character it would not work, as normal PCs are too large for that, but as your PC (as you disclosed earlier on this site) is a tiny fey only 4 inches large, this works.
The writers of the spell probably did not consider that a creature trapped in the cage form of forcecage and small enough could try to just escape through the bars. And because the spell says

A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means.

it technically couldn't, even if it did fit through, but in your case, you are fitting through by magical means.
You don't need the "harmless sensory effect" puff of wind from druidcraft to make it work.
Note that there is an extremely highly upvoted answer to Is escaping from a cage-shaped Forcecage really as ridiculously easy as it seems?, that takes the opposite position, namely that you cannot leave by "mundane movement", even if it is from a magical form, like gaseous form. I think this is too narrow a reading of "leave by magical means". If the intent was that you only can teleport out of the cage, it would have been easy to just say that.
To me, also from a balance perspective, it would be wise of the DM to interpret the means of escape as generously as possible. Forcecage is a pretty broken spell that does not even allow for a saving throw, requires no concentration, and has no costly components that get used up. It's like a cheat button to remove powerful enemies from a fight and slaughter them at leisure with arrows and ranged attacks like eldritch blast.

P.S. For your added comment question, bullets tend to be very heavy relative to their size, a light, organic teeny-tiny creature would experience a lot of air friction slowing it down relative to its mass, and would make a bad bullet.

I’m not sure this follows. The magical effect is only shrinking you. It isn’t causing you to escape. It seems that simply moving between the bars while small enough is escaping by non-magical means, not matter how you got that size.

The game engine is optimized for Medium sized creatures as PCs. Tiny, and large (or larger) run into some problems, and small run into a few problems as well.

@ThomasMarkov would I be able to escape using druidcraft for the sensory gust of wind, assuming I can fit, because the wind was made magically?

@ThomasMarkov I think I understand what you mean. For comparison, would you also rule that you cannot escape with gaseous form? If that worked, is it because is has a movement component, and you read "leave by magic" as "move by magic"? If the tiny creature had fly would that work, because now they are moving magically? Longstrider? I think if they meant just teleporting out, they would have said so. To me, leaving by magical means in a wider sense encompasses any way that enables you to leave and involves magic.

@NobodytheHobgoblin it might be similar to the related question about if escaping from the cage shaped force cage is easy, where walking and flying are mundane, whereas teleportation or being pushed by a magical force at high speed are extraordinary

@Tasi, Yes, maybe. Even though the PC is very light, I'm not sure if the "sensory effect" of a puff of wind would be enough to move the PC. Sensory effect means it is so weak, you can feel it, but it has no other effects like moving you around. A benevolent DM of course could make exception for your very low weight. So you might better find something else that can move you in that case if you want to be sure. To be honest, if I were the DM, I would just ignore that you cannot move out without magic if you are that small, but of course, your DM might not see it that way.

@NobodytheHobgoblin is there a feat that could give a non-sensory push? Because I have no class or race features that I can find for a non-sensory magical push

@Tasi perhaps a friend with the Telekinetic feat from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything could shove you out.
